# Specify order of pipelines and dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm having a hard time getting a grasp on this to be honest.
Right now my lab project is as follows:

**PR to master** -> **Triggers Pre-Build Pipeline** as condition to merge the code ->

On merge **Infrastructure pipe runs only if any changes happen in my Infrastructure folder** ->

On merge I want to **run my deploy pipeline** to deploy my web app to Azure.

---

The pipes in question do the things they ought to, i.e.

**Pre build** builds, publishes artifact, runs Unit tests, validates ARM templates.

**Infra pipe** deploys the necessary infra for my web app such as ResourceGroup, App plan, app service, key vault.

**Deploy Pipe** downloads the artifact produced in pre deploy and deploys to a stage slot and swaps it to production slot.

---

**What I can't seem to get to work is the pipeline chaining through dependencies**, if changes happen to both infra and web app code in master I want the infra pipe to **run first** and the deploy pipe only if it succeeds.

If I merge **only app code** I want **only the deploy pipe** to run regardless if the infra pipe ran or not.

If I merge **only infra code** I want **only the infra pipe** to run.

If I merge **both app and infra code** I want **both infra and deploy pipe** to run **in specific order**.

I feel this shouldn't be all that hard to accomplish, but I've spent way too much time trying to solve this to no avail, anyone able to help? :)

---

Edit:

Hey Sorry @HughLin-MSFT Been Trying to work around this a bit since we're trying to avoid running scripts left and right. :)

I saw you have Build Queuing planned in an upcoming release so for now I think we might have to wait for that.

If I were to merge my deploy and infra pipe, can I use:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - Infrastructure/*
```

At stage level and somehow skip a stage instead? 
Seen multiple articles mention "Continue if skipped" but can't find any information on how to actually skip a stage.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT
Added to my question :)

Comment: `At stage level and somehow skip a stage instead?`For this issue ,when you run pipeline,you can choose [which stages to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blftb.png).

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I assume that this isn't available in code yet? I mean like adding a [Build policy](https://imgur.com/a/y9KpPSZ) for Build validation for a PR? :)

Comment: I give a rough idea  in update，please view it. In addition ,I am not clear what the build policy has to do with this issue.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT
What I meant was you can do most of the work in code, but a bunch of stuff needs to be handled in the GUI (I have no doubt this will improve over time) or by running scripts on the side. We have a script that sets up a project, inits a few repos, sets a few policies etc. But we'd like to be able to not run scripts in the middle of our pipeline to control the flow of the pipes/jobs (like setting a priority order/queue order on pipelines). Stages to run is currently only available in the GUI on manual triggering am I right?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT
If what I've read is true that MS promotes a single multi stage pipe from end-to-end, then I need to be able to use conditions to skip/branch stages without running side scripts.
The functionality to check for changed code in the repos already exists since you can point the trigger to branch/folder with the includes/excludes so scripting cancellations of jobs seem suboptimal to be honest.
It'd allow for massively reduced run times being able to do this properly and lessen the maintenance of keeping extra scripts documented and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

For the first and second cases, you just need to set `Path filters` in Triggers, the pipeline only triggers when the file at the specified path is changed. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#path-filters-in-azure-pipelines-and-team-foundation-services-tfs).

[image]

For the third case, you can try to add two agent jobs in the `infra pipe`, add `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` task to the second agent job to trigger the `deploy pipe`, and then set `Only when all previous jobs have succeeded` in `Run this job` drop-down box for job2. In addition, you need to add a powershell task before the `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` task, and use a script to detect whether there is app code, run job2 if there is, and cancel job2 if not.

[image]

**Update**:

1. First you can create a new pipeline and create a variable:`changedcode`
2. Use [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#response) rest api to get the commit , then get the changed code folder with [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.
3. Assign changed code folder name as value to `changedcode` variable.
4. Set [custom conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for the agent job. In the `Infra` job, if the `changedcode` variable value is `Infra`, run the `Infra` job. In the `Infra` job, use the [Builds-Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body) rest api or `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` task to trigger the `Infra` pipeline. The same is true for `Deploy` job, the only difference is the custom condition expression.

Here is a sample structure in yaml:

```
jobs:
  variables: 
    changedcode: ""
- job:
  steps:
  - powershell： |
    #Get the changed code folder with rest api

- job: Infra 
  condition: containsValue($(changedcode), "Infra"))
  - powershell： |
    #queue Infra pipeline with rest api or Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline task

- job: Deploy
  condition: (containsValue($(changedcode), "deploy")),and ....
 - powershell： |
  #queue Deploy pipeline with rest api or Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline task
```